# Import file from Excel into SAS Error Meesage

Tags: excel, import, sas, proc

I am trying to import a `2007 MS Excel` into `SAS`. I use `SAS 9.2.` with the `Acces` module for PC file already installed. I used the next code:

```
 proc import datafile = 'C:\saspractica\Excel.xlsx' out= work.auto1 dbms = excel REPLACE;
 sheet = 'auto';
 GETNAMES = YES;
 run;
```

Nevertheless, `SAS` shows me the next message:

> ERROR: Connect: external table does not have expected format. ERROR:
>   Error in the LIBNAME statement. Connection Failed.  See log for
>   details. NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of
>   errors. NOTE: PROCEDURE IMPORT used (Total process time):
>         real time           0.21 seconds
>         cpu time            0.14 seconds

I have checked the code and changed `dbms = xlsx` to `dbms=excel`. However, the error message continues... Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Do you have SAS 9.2 TS1M2 or greater? Before this release you can't import .xlsx files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have SAS 9.2 (TS1M2) or greater you can try something like the following using the libname method. This will work on a Windows machine, but not a Unix one.

Set up a library that references your excel file like below:

```
libname datain excel 'C:\saspractica\Excel.xlsx';
```

Then navigate to the explorer window and open the library to view the sheet and sheet names. If the sheet name is auto try the following:

```
data want;
set data.auto;
run;
```

If the sheet name is auto$ try the following instead:

```
data want;
set data.'auto$'n;
run;
```

Close the connection to the library/file when you finish the import

```
libname datain;
```